# C#- Print Exisitng PDF using Microsoft Printer

Tags: c#, automation

I am new to C# and i would like to automate the printing of existing PDFs in Microsoft Print to PDF using C#.

I have gone through multiple questions raised for similar concern , however i am not able to get a  concrete method to pass the pdf file for printing.

I tried the below code but it ends up in printing an empty PDF.
using System.Drawing.Printing;

internal class Program

{

```
private static void Main(string[] args)

{

   

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

   

    //string file = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    string file = "reprinted_";

    Console.WriteLine(file);

    string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

// string dir = Environment.;

```
    string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Temp\pdf_out");



    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);



    foreach (var fil in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))

    {

        // Rest of the code goes here

        Console.WriteLine(fil.FullName);

        Console.WriteLine(file);

        Console.WriteLine(fil.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(directory);

        try

        {

            streamToPrint = new StreamReader(fil.FullName);



            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()



            {

               

                PrinterSettings  = new PrinterSettings()

                {

                    //doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);

                    // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'

                    PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",



                    // tell the object this document will print to file

                    PrintToFile = true,

                   

                    // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)

                    PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + fil.Name + ".pdf"),

                }

            };

           

            doc.Print();

            //Console.ReadLine();

        }

        finally

        //Console.ReadKey(true);

    }

}
```

}

it would be great if someone can guide me explaining how to pass the pdf for printing . The microsoft documentation of PrintDocument class explains passing of non-pdf files such as .docx, .txt, .png files but nowhere explained about PDF files.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the information. However i have a requirement where some pdf has html content and link and in order to remove that I am reprinting using Microsoft Print to PDF so that it will be a plain PDF.  Could you help me with the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"");
foreach (var item in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
string existingPathName = item.Directory.FullName;
string notExistingFileName = item.Directory.FullName + "\\Output\\" + item.Name;

if (Directory.Exists(existingPathName) && !File.Exists(notExistingFileName))
                {
                    PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
                    pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
                    pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = notExistingFileName;
                    pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
                    PrintPageEventHandler pdoc_PrintPage = null;
                    pdoc.PrintPage += pdoc_PrintPage;
                    pdoc.Print();
                }
            }
```

Don't worry we will find solution soon